# Stop fragment refresh when using NavGraph in Bottom Navigation

Tags: java, android, kotlin, navigation, bottomnavigationview

I am using navigationGraph and bottom navigation.I know that fragments are recreate every time bottomnavigation buttons are clicked in BottomNavigation. If there is already a fragment created  I don't want the fragment to be refreshed in bottomnavigation passes like in other applications(like twitter,instagram etc.).  When I return to MainFragment again, all views are recreated again and unnecessarily pulls data from the database again. Many questions have been asked about this, but none of them worked as I wanted. Any suggestions?

I uploaded a photo. When I go back to MainFragment from other fragments, MainFragment is recreated again .[image: When I go back to MainFragment from other fragments, MainFragment is recreated again.]

Main Activity code;

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    navController=findNavController(R.id.main_fragmentContainerView)
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.mainFragment,
            R.id.searchFragment,
            R.id.userProfileFragment
        )
    )

    bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)
}

override fun onNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return navController.navigateUp()||super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

MainFragment

```
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        readDatabase()
}
```

Comment: There's no "refresh" happening at all unless you ask for one. Any data you've already loaded and cached in a `ViewModel` is already instantly available, without any refresh, etc. required. Show your fragment code and how you load your data for that fragment if you want help with not avoiding reloading data that is already available.

Comment: I updated the question. In short, I don't want the views to be recreated again and again when I switch the bottomnavigationview elements like in Instagram. I want it to continue from the item it left in the Recyclerview.

Comment: The views being recreated doesn't have anything to do with [saving your state](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state). RecyclerView already restores its position exactly where you left off, whether the view is recreated or not - there's a [whole blog post about that](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/restore-recyclerview-scroll-position-a8fbdc9a9334). You haven't actually included any of the code for how you load your data or fill in your RecyclerView.

Comment: Thank you.I got it.But there is a pulling data from Firebase database in my OnviewCreated.I don't want to pull data from firebase again and again. I have to redo everything I do in Onviewcreate. Downloading data, displaying in recyclerview, creating adapter etc. I don't want this. I can create static data and control it, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Like I said in the first comment, your data loading should be in a ViewModel, where it is instantly available to your new UI without any waiting at all. Show. Your. Code.